# Chrome versus local javascript from bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome

I'm debugging a piece of Javascript that is normally used as follows: a bookmark has a javascript: url that includes:

```
_readability_script.src='http://somewhere.com/readability.js?x='+(Math.random());document.documentElement.appendChild(_readability_script)
```

To debug some mods, I tried to just change that to a file:/// url, and I am rewarded with:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///users/benson/readability.js?x=0.29405178176239133
```

What sense does this make? My bookmark can pull heaven knows what from some random web server, but it can't read from a local file?

More to the point, is there a setting somewhere that I can use to allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you host the files on your local test web server? That way it meets the local and website criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, web pages aren't allowed to automatically load data from your local file system.  Think about it, do you want a site you casually browse to accessing your private files?

Comment: It's not a web page, it's a bookmark. And the original could be loading arbitrary malware. I'm sort of more surprised that the original works than that the modification does not.

Comment: @bmargulies, bookmarks run in the context of the current page, so it's considered an internet page too.  You're right that the browser doesn't know if readability.js is malware.  It's just part of the current browser security model that cross-domain script loads are possible.  That's how, e.g. [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) works.  It's also why people use things like NoScript.